# HTML - Setting container background & height @ 100% minimum

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I have created a simple, dynamic page using Bootstrap. It has a sticky nav bar as well as a sticky footer.

- I have the navbar, footer and page content to be black.
- I **want** the main content area to be white & the sides of page black as per
  background.

I can only achieve this at the moment, by setting a physical height, not by using height:100%;

Could someone please help by looking at my existing code, to see what I am doing wrong.

I don't think I am using the 'div push' idea properly either, as I can see the white push box on the page.

```
<div id="push"></div>
```

[Picture of desired Result](http://i59.tinypic.com/2roq8gg.png) - when content is larger than page, user will scroll but footer always sticky. I believe this will already work.

[JSFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/bkL53/)

[Bootstrap Sticky Footer with Sticky Nav Code](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a simpler approach.  Look carefully at the CSS, especially the **position:fixed** property/value.

If you add more content or make your window smaller, you will see it scrolls as desired.  This is a simplified version of what I found [here](http://www.flashjunior.ch/school/footers/fixed.cfm).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fixed Footer</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{ margin:0px; padding:0px;background:black}

    #maincontent{
        width:500px;
        background:#fff;
        padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    #footer{
        position:fixed;
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        width:100%;
        background:#990000;
        line-height:30px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #footer span{padding-left:20px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="maincontent">
    <h1>Fixierter Footer, nur mit CSS</h1>
    <p>Das Folgende Script macht genau das, nur halt im CSS alleine.</p>
    <p>Das Folgende Script macht genau das, nur halt im CSS alleine.</p>
    <p>Das Folgende Script macht genau das, nur halt im CSS alleine.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><span>Ich bin Footer, der immer hier unten bleibt :-)</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I managed to do that myself. The main issue I am having is that I want to set the main content area to have a white background with 100% page height, even when there is not as much content on the page. (see screenshot in original post).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `push` goes right before the `footer`, and doesn't need a specific height set in the CSS..

http://jsfiddle.net/ugeVP/

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on getting the middle section (content area) to have a white background, full page regardless of the size of content.

Comment: Check out this one: http://www.bootply.com/123464 -- The center will scroll once content is more than 100% height.

Comment: I changed it to `container-fluid` for full width, but you can change those back to `container` if you don't want that.